# Adding Library to project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, mupdf

I am working with mupdf library for rendering pdf files in my android application.

For that i built mupdf library using ndk and different tools.

Now i want to add this compiled code to my project in android studio.

I am quite new to android studio so not able to do it.

So can some one help me with.

I am trying to follow [this](http://ssahinkoc.blogspot.in/2014/10/integration-of-mupdf-project-as-library.html) link.

Answer (score 2):

You add your library in your libs directory like here:

```
C:\Users\Blabala\Desktop\Project\app\libs
```

and then you write in gradle this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

also you can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHEvI_G6UtI) tutorial. More information [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

**UPDATE:**

```
C:\Users\Balbala\Desktop\appname\Library
```

just add the library in project then rebuild the project and you are good to go

But you will have to change the manifest of Library like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.blabala">

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="4"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <application/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: but my library has a whole project.It is not a jar
How could i add >?

Comment: If it helped then accept the answer if it did not ask me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Put the library in your project: `<project>/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libmupdf.so`